# How does ElasticSearch calculate Term Frequency under ill-posed condition like matching phrase "b b" in "b b b b b b b b b b"?

Tags: elasticsearch

**EDIT:** 
Bad example I gave. My use case was actually Chinese characters, i.e., phrase match "我我" in "我我我我我我我我我我". So for those who aren't familiar with Chinese search engine, the question really is searching "b b" in "b b b b b b b b b b", NOT "bb" in "bbbbbbbbbb". **I also edited title to avoid confusions.**

Bonus question: what's the frequency if "phrase match prefix" is used instead with "max_expansions = 4"?

**original post:**
Suppose the search keyword is "bb", the document is "bbbbbbbbbb" (10 b's). Type is analyzed and let's say 'b' is the "atomic term" that gets indexed.

I imagine the document is represented internally as something like this: {'b':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], metadata: {...}} where the numbers are the locations of the term 'b'. Correct me if I am wrong.

Term frequency tf(t in d) = sqrt(frequency) according to the elastic guide. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#tf)
So when "bb" is **phrase matched** against the doc with 10 b's, what's the frequency, is it 5 or 9?

Answer (score 0):

when you use "standard analyzer" the "bbbbbbbbb" will be analyze as "0:bbbbbbbbb" not this {'b':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. and searching "bb" does not have any result. if the phrase in docs is something like "b b b b b b b b b" then {'b':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] is correct. but again if you search "bb", there will be no result. 
but if you search something like "b b" it will analyze to "b" or "b" and the frequency in docs is 9 (maybe 9+9/2).

with this API you can see how score was calculated:

> GET /my_index/doc/_search?explain

more information about scoring:

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

Comment: Bad example I gave. My use case was actually Chinese characters, i.e., phrase match "我我" in "我我我我我我我我我我", which is similar to searching "i i" in "i i i i i i i i i i". So, phrase matching just checks match at every position of 'i' regardless of  overlaps?  Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: it is explained here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html

Comment: If there is more "i" in a doc, so it have more score.